# how to give each user a unique url

Tags: php, apache

favorite
I am building a website and I would like to customize the users' profile so their profile url shares their name. For example, the website domain would be www.example.com and the users' url would be www.example.com/username.

at present when i do a test sign it looks like test/admin/index.php
i want to rewrite it as test/admin/testuser

I am assuming this is a convention because I see this all around the web. Is this done by giving each user their own directory and how painstaking would that be?

Comment: no, that's done through url routing. the url you see does not need to match a directory structure.

Comment: can help me with some example

Comment: google + "php url routing"

Comment: Do you use a CMS or a framework?

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is done by routing. You redirect all requests to the index.php file with .htaccess

Your setup could look like this:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

if(empty($_GET['param'])) {
    // code for frontpage
} else {
    $username = $_GET['param'];
}

?>
```

Comment: i tried as same not working by changing params to usr_name

Answer (score 0):

In your htaccess you can try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And in your php:

```
if(isset($_GET['user'])) {
    // code for frontpage
} else {
    $username = $_GET['user'];
}
```

I hope this help you